# Authorize.net CCV code

Tags: credit-card, verification, authorize.net

I implemented CIM(Customer Information Manager) where customers create their profile with credit card information. And I (Merchant) use to get
payments by standard payment method in CIM (by pressing "Pay Now" button on merchant page).
Now confusion is that, there are some payment transaction which give error when I press button "Pay Now" that is "CCV is invalid".

I visited forums and found that customer can not save his CCV within customer profile. My question is that while createCustomerProfileRequest,
CCV is in parameter list that we supply as input. If CCV is not being saved in customer profile then why it is in customer profile input parameters?(Edit: remember, customer profile is not on my local database, its on authorize.net)
How can I cope this issue "CCV is invalid" while doing transaction? should I ping the customer that "Please give me your CCV code, because it is
not saved by authorize.net customer profile, and I need to complete the transaction" ?

I will be thankful to you...

Comment: LOLz, leppie, Actually I want that save these info on Authorize.net as CC number and Expiration date is already being saved there.

Comment: Sorry I understood wrong. I guess you will have to contact them, both Paypal and Google Wallet stores this info.

Answer (score 0):

CVV is verified when the CIM profile is created. After that it is discarded as it is no longer required for future purchases through CIM. If you are getting a CVV error when making payments using CIM then you are making an incorrect API call.